# Github3.py 1.3.0 Get timestamp for commit

Tags: python, github, github3.py

I looked through the documentation and even the source code and I can't seem to figure out how to get the timestamp of a commit using the github3.py library. I'm, pretty sure it's there because, well, it's a timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you want to get a timestamp that's related to a git commit stored in GitHub, then you'll need to have a few things:

- The Repository that contains the commit
- The SHA
- What you define as timestamp (is that the datetime it was authored, or datetime it was committed - note these are not always guaranteed to be equal)

So if you have the repository you'd retrieve it like so:

```
repo = github3.repository('username', 'repositoryname')
```

With that, you should be able to get the `git_commit` data like so:

```
commit = repo.git_commit('sha1-of-git-commit-i-care-about')
```

Your `commit` value is an instance of a [`github3.git.Commit`](https://github3.readthedocs.io/en/master/api-reference/git.html#github3.git.Commit) object which has `author` and `committer` attributes which are dictionaries that look like

```
  "author": {
    "date": "2014-11-07T22:01:45Z",
    "name": "Scott Chacon",
    "email": "schacon@gmail.com"
  },
  "committer": {
    "date": "2014-11-07T22:01:45Z",
    "name": "Scott Chacon",
    "email": "schacon@gmail.com"
  },
```

So you can wrap this up with:

```
commit.author["date"]
```

I suggest using a utility like `dateutil` to parse these timestamps.

Comment: DeprecationWarning: The anonymous API function `github3.api.repository` is deprecated. Use `GitHub.repository` instead.